# Is it natural to use the verb "stomp" in the sense of getting something off one's feet?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it natural to use the verb *stomp* in the sense of getting something off one's feet? For example:

> Before you come in, please **stomp off** the snow of your feet.

If it is not, the what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: I think 'stomp' is mainly American. I am British, and would prefer 'stamp the snow off my shoes'.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree there. Any dictionary or corpus evidence that stomp is mostly American?

Comment: stomp verb (UK stamp) to put a foot down on the ground hard and quickly, making a loud noise, often to show anger [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stomp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of stomp with direct object works well for me.

I would phrase it as "stomp the snow off your boots".  You hopefully don't have snow on your *feet*.  And it is not the "snow of your boots" but "stomp X off Y"

Answer (score 1):

"Stomp" is regional dialect. While it's now included in various American dictionaries, it comes from the Standard English term "stamp." So in a place where everyone uses "stomp," it would be understood and not stand out, but technically, it's not correct in formal English. If you want to use local terms, "stomp" is fine in the U.S. But I'm an older American and when I hear the term "stomp" it still jars me because I grew up speaking Standard English.

Comment: Stomp, first recorded 1803, (in USA) so not a very new word.  Stomp now has a different meaning to stamp

Comment: I kind of imagine that catfish stomping is a redneck sport.